# how to keep the document from autoscrolling when i add content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a web app that has content like a facebook wall. when you click a button it adds more content at the end of the current content then should scroll to it. but currently if im scrolled any amount down, when i add the content the page suddenly scrolls down a seemingly random amount, and I have not added the scroll-to code yet. Why is the page auto scrolling? and how do i get it to stop?

Comment: its a massive project, ill see if i can replicate it on jsfiddle

Comment: before adding content, check scrollTop() value and when inserted new content scroll again to this value, could work

Comment: Using document.body as the container I can't seem to reproduce your issue in IE9, FF or Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/3XFaE/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this without looking to far into what your code might be would just be offsetting what you add.  So using some js find out the height the new content would add and then when you add it, scroll down that amount

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not exactly sure why it's happening, I do know that you *should* be able to play around with CSS to avoid any scrolling while adding content to the page.   If you set the `body` *overflow* to *hidden* PRIOR to adding the content, then setting it back to *visible* afterward, you should be able to prevent any scrolling from happening.

If you're using jQuery, something like this:

```
$(document.body).css('overflow','hidden');
// do your stuff here e.g.
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++) {
   $(document.body).append('<div>some content to append here</div>');
}
$(document.body).css('overflow','visible');
```

NOTE: if it's a 3rd party library that's appending the content and they're using JS to scroll the page, this solution may not work.